# how to sync an id of an object with a backend via restKit?

Tags: restkit

I have a Topic object which i created on the client-side iPhone.
When I post it to the server the topicID attribute was set to null.
now I wish to update that topic but I don't know the id of that topic.

Does anyone knows how to solve it?

I've tried to delete the created topic from the local store and fetch for new topics from the server but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If some one is interested the answer is that when the client receives a response it updates the id